# RuntimeError: A secret key is required to use CSRF. I have used a secret key but it still seems to give the error

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

This is the code that I have include in **flask_blog.py** while making the web app. I have mentioned the SECRET_KEY. Can anybody please look into it and let me know what the possible error is in this code. Thanks in advance.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, flash, redirect
from forms import RegistrationForm, LoginForm

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY']='key'
posts=[
    {
        'author':'HC Verma',
        'title':'First blog Post',
        'content':'first post content'
    },
    {
        'author':'RD Sharma',
        'title':'Second blog Post',
        'content':'second post content'
    }
]


@app.route("/")
@app.route("/home")
def home():
    return render_template('home.html', posts=posts)


@app.route("/about")
def about():
    return render_template('about.html', title='About')


@app.route("/register", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    form = RegistrationForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        flash(f'Account created for {form.username.data}!', 'success')
        return redirect(url_for('home'))
    return render_template('register.html', title='Register', form=form)


@app.route("/login", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        if form.email.data == 'abc@gmail.com' and form.password.data == 'password':
            flash('You have been logged in!', 'success')
            return redirect(url_for('home'))
        else:
            flash('Login Unsuccessful. Please check username and password', 'danger')
    return render_template('login.html', title='Login', form=form)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Edit: Here is the runtime error that I am facing and I am adding the link to the screenshot here.
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W5Fos.png)

Also adding the forms.py file which has the RegistrationForm and LoginForm classes.

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, PasswordField, SubmitField, 
   BooleanField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, Length, Email, EqualTo


class RegistrationForm(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField('Username',
                           validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=2, 
    max=20)])
    email = StringField('Email',
                        validators=[DataRequired(), Email()])
    password = PasswordField('Password', validators=[DataRequired()])
    confirm_password = PasswordField('Confirm Password',
                                     validators=[DataRequired(), 
    EqualTo('password')])
    submit = SubmitField('Sign Up')


class LoginForm(FlaskForm):
    email = StringField('Email',
                        validators=[DataRequired(), Email()])
    password = PasswordField('Password', validators=[DataRequired()])
    remember = BooleanField('Remember Me')
    submit = SubmitField('Login')
```

Edit:2
Here are the two templates
1)register.html-makes the template for registration page

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="content-section">
        <form method="POST" action="">
            {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
            <fieldset class="form-group">
                <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Join Today</legend>
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ form.username.label(class="form-control-label") }}

                    {% if form.username.errors %}
                        {{ form.username(class="form-control form-control-lg is-invalid") }}
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                            {% for error in form.username.errors %}
                                <span>{{ error }}</span>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </div>
                    {% else %}
                        {{ form.username(class="form-control form-control-lg") }}
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ form.email.label(class="form-control-label") }}
                    {% if form.email.errors %}
                        {{ form.email(class="form-control form-control-lg is-invalid") }}
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                            {% for error in form.email.errors %}
                                <span>{{ error }}</span>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </div>
                    {% else %}
                        {{ form.email(class="form-control form-control-lg") }}
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ form.password.label(class="form-control-label") }}
                    {% if form.password.errors %}
                        {{ form.password(class="form-control form-control-lg is-invalid") }}
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                            {% for error in form.password.errors %}
                                <span>{{ error }}</span>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </div>
                    {% else %}
                        {{ form.password(class="form-control form-control-lg") }}
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ form.confirm_password.label(class="form-control-label") }}
                    {% if form.confirm_password.errors %}
                        {{ form.confirm_password(class="form-control form-control-lg is-invalid") }}
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                            {% for error in form.confirm_password.errors %}
                                <span>{{ error }}</span>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </div>
                    {% else %}
                        {{ form.confirm_password(class="form-control form-control-lg") }}
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
            </fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ form.submit(class="btn btn-outline-info") }}
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="border-top pt-3">
        <small class="text-muted">
            Already Have An Account? <a class="ml-2" href="{{ url_for('login') }}">Sign In</a>
        </small>
    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

2. login.html-makes the template for login page

   ```
        {% extends "layout.html" %}
    {% block content %}
        <div class="content-section">
            <form method="POST" action="">
                {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
        <fieldset class="form-group">
            <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Log In Page</legend>
                     <div class="form-group">
                        {{ form.email.label(class="form-class-label") }}
                        {% if form.email.errors %}
                        {{ form.email(class="form-control form-control-lg is-invalid") }}
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                            {% for error in form.password.errors %}
                            <span> error </span>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </div>
                        {%else%}
    {   (class="form-control form-control-lg") }}
                        {% endif %}
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        {{ form.password.label(class="form-class-label") }}
                        {% if form.password.errors %}
                        {{ form.password(class="form-control form-control-lg is-invalid") }}
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                            {% for error in form.password.errors %}
                            <span>{{error}} </span>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </div>
                        {%else%}
    {                       {{ form.password(class="form-control form-control-lg") }}
                        {% endif %}
                    </div>
                   <div class="form-check">
                    {{ form.remember(class="form-check-input") }}
                    {{ form.remember(class="form-class=label") }}
                   </div>
        </fieldset>
        <div class="form-group">
            {{ form.submit(class="btn btn-outline-info") }}
        </div>
        <small class="text-muted ml-2"> 
            <a href="#">
                Forgot Password?
            </a></small>
        </form>

        </div>
        <div class="border-top pt-3">
            <small class="text-muted">
                Need an account? Log in <a class="ml-2" href="{{ url_for('register') }}">
                Sign Up</a>
            </small>
        </div>

    {% endblock content %}
   ```

I have added both the files,templates and the screenshot as asked in the comments.
Let me know what is wrong in the following code.

Comment: Your key is not so secret now. You should flag your post for a moderator to remove this key. Don’t edit your post. There is edit history, so anyone can view it.

Comment: please add your forms and form templates to the question.

Comment: Can you provide actual error log that you receive?

Comment: @simkusr I have added the link to the screenshot, please look into it and let me know the error

Comment: @gittert I edited the question and have added them.

Comment: You havent added the templates (html files for login and register).

Comment: @gittert added the html files now. Thank you

Comment: If I run your code, it works without errors on CSRF. If I remove the app.config secret key i get the runtime error. I do however see an error in your login template in the if form.email.errors. Have a closer look there. Are you sure you run in debug mode and restarted the app, clear browser cache just to be sure?

Comment: @gittert I made the changes with the login.html file. But still, it gives me the CSRF error. I tried clearing my browser cache too but doesn't seem to help much. Yes, I am running in the debug mode and have restarted it several times. Also tried changing the key if that was a problem, but not resolving the error.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I have just tried out your code samples and with small changes it works (but nonethless, I haven't received missing SECRET KEY, but keep on reading)

`app.py` - so here I have modified only `home` and `about` endpoints as I don't have those `.html` files, now just redirecting to `register` page. Also in `register` and `login` I also redirect to a different endpoints after success login/register as I do not have `home` endpoint `.html` file.

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, flash, redirect
from forms import RegistrationForm, LoginForm

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = '84da5b8a39a6d06bf8bc7a60cedcac93'
posts = [
    {
        'author': 'HC Verma',
        'title': 'First blog Post',
        'content': 'first post content'
    },
    {
        'author': 'RD Sharma',
        'title': 'Second blog Post',
        'content': 'second post content'
    }
]


@app.route("/")
@app.route("/home")
def home():
    # return render_template('home.html', posts=posts)
    return redirect(url_for('register'))


@app.route("/about")
def about():
    # return render_template('about.html', title='About')
    return redirect(url_for('register'))


@app.route("/register", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    form = RegistrationForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        flash(f'Account created for {form.username.data}!', 'success')
        return redirect(url_for('login'))
    return render_template('register.html', title='Register', form=form)


@app.route("/login", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        if form.email.data == 'abc@gmail.com' and form.password.data == 'password':
            flash('You have been logged in!', 'success')
            return redirect(url_for('register'))
        else:
            flash('Login Unsuccessful. Please check username and password', 'danger')
    return render_template('login.html', title='Login', form=form)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

`forms.py` - I haven't done any changes to it.

```py
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, PasswordField, SubmitField, BooleanField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, Length, Email, EqualTo


class RegistrationForm(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField('Username',
                           validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=2, 
    max=20)])
    email = StringField('Email',
                        validators=[DataRequired(), Email()])
    password = PasswordField('Password', validators=[DataRequired()])
    confirm_password = PasswordField('Confirm Password',
                                     validators=[DataRequired(), 
    EqualTo('password')])
    submit = SubmitField('Sign Up')


class LoginForm(FlaskForm):
    email = StringField('Email',
                        validators=[DataRequired(), Email()])
    password = PasswordField('Password', validators=[DataRequired()])
    remember = BooleanField('Remember Me')
    submit = SubmitField('Login')
```

`layout.html` - I have created my own just for rendering `register` and `login` pages

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

{% block content %}{% endblock %}

</body>
</html>
```

`register.html` - no changes were made

```html
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="content-section">
        <form method="POST" action="">
            {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
            <fieldset class="form-group">
                <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Join Today</legend>
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ form.username.label(class="form-control-label") }}

                    {% if form.username.errors %}
                        {{ form.username(class="form-control form-control-lg is-invalid") }}
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                            {% for error in form.username.errors %}
                                <span>{{ error }}</span>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </div>
                    {% else %}
                        {{ form.username(class="form-control form-control-lg") }}
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ form.email.label(class="form-control-label") }}
                    {% if form.email.errors %}
                        {{ form.email(class="form-control form-control-lg is-invalid") }}
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                            {% for error in form.email.errors %}
                                <span>{{ error }}</span>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </div>
                    {% else %}
                        {{ form.email(class="form-control form-control-lg") }}
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ form.password.label(class="form-control-label") }}
                    {% if form.password.errors %}
                        {{ form.password(class="form-control form-control-lg is-invalid") }}
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                            {% for error in form.password.errors %}
                                <span>{{ error }}</span>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </div>
                    {% else %}
                        {{ form.password(class="form-control form-control-lg") }}
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ form.confirm_password.label(class="form-control-label") }}
                    {% if form.confirm_password.errors %}
                        {{ form.confirm_password(class="form-control form-control-lg is-invalid") }}
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                            {% for error in form.confirm_password.errors %}
                                <span>{{ error }}</span>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </div>
                    {% else %}
                        {{ form.confirm_password(class="form-control form-control-lg") }}
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
            </fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ form.submit(class="btn btn-outline-info") }}
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="border-top pt-3">
        <small class="text-muted">
            Already Have An Account? <a class="ml-2" href="{{ url_for('login') }}">Sign In</a>
        </small>
    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

`login.html` - here I made some changes, first I have fixed the login form.

1. Fixed html typos:

from

```html
                  <div class="form-group">
                     {{ form.email.label(class="form-class-label") }}
                     {% if form.email.errors %}
                     {{ form.email(class="form-control form-control-lg is-invalid") }}
                     <div class="invalid-feedback">
                         {% for error in form.password.errors %}
                         <span> error </span>
                         {% endfor %}
                     </div>
                     {%else%}
 {   (class="form-control form-control-lg") }}
                     {% endif %}
                 </div>
```

to

```html
                 <div class="form-group">
                    {{ form.email.label(class="form-class-label") }}
                    {% if form.email.errors %}
                    {{ form.email(class="form-control form-control-lg is-invalid") }}
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                        {% for error in form.password.errors %}
                        <span> error </span>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                    {%else%}
                        <div class="form-control form-control-lg"></div>
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
```

2. `password` field was incorrect

```html
{                       {{ form.password(class="form-control form-control-lg") }}
```

changed to

```html
{{ form.password(class="form-control form-control-lg") }}
```

3. `email` field was missing so I have added

```html
{{ form.email(class="form-control form-control-lg") }}
```

And so the end result is like this:

```html
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="content-section">
        <form method="POST" action="">
            {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
    <fieldset class="form-group">
        <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Log In Page</legend>
                 <div class="form-group">
                    {{ form.email.label(class="form-class-label") }}
                    {% if form.email.errors %}
                    {{ form.email(class="form-control form-control-lg is-invalid") }}
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                        {% for error in form.password.errors %}
                        <span> error </span>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                    {%else%}
                        <div class="form-control form-control-lg"></div>
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ form.password.label(class="form-class-label") }}
                    {% if form.password.errors %}
                        {{ form.password(class="form-control form-control-lg is-invalid") }}
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                            {% for error in form.password.errors %}
                            <span>{{error}} </span>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </div>
                    {%else%}
                       {{ form.email(class="form-control form-control-lg") }}
                       {{ form.password(class="form-control form-control-lg") }}
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
               <div class="form-check">
                {{ form.remember(class="form-check-input") }}
                {{ form.remember(class="form-class=label") }}
               </div>
    </fieldset>
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ form.submit(class="btn btn-outline-info") }}
    </div>
    <small class="text-muted ml-2"> 
        <a href="#">
            Forgot Password?
        </a></small>
    </form>

    </div>
    <div class="border-top pt-3">
        <small class="text-muted">
            Need an account? Log in <a class="ml-2" href="{{ url_for('register') }}">
            Sign Up</a>
        </small>
    </div>

{% endblock content %}
```

So the code that you have provided works fine, this means that you have a different place where this error is coming up. Possible situation when a secret key is missing even if you have provided in `app.config` is when you are not using flask `jinja2` engine and sending requests using e.g. jquery `ajax` or similar calls, which means that these calls that are not coming from `jinja2` forms are missing `secret key` and to solve it you need to provide the secret key for a request - for this you can read and see more examples in [flask-wtf](https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/csrf.html) docs.